# How To Draw The Circumcircle of a Given Triangle by Calculating the Circumcenter

Tags: java

I´m trying to make a code that enables the user to click in 3 points on a window and then the code will automaticly generate a triangle with said points. The code is also suposed to draw the incircle and circumcircle of the generated triangle. So far I have been able to make it work for the incircle that its properly centered and it is  able to create the circumcircle but it´s not properly centered given the fact that i haven´t been able to figure out how to calculate the circumcenter of said triangle.

If any of you have any tip in how to calculate the circumcenter in my case I would really appreciate it. Thank a lot in Advanced

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Color.BLACK;
import static java.awt.Color.BLUE;
import static java.awt.Color.RED;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import javax.swing.JComponent;





public class graficadorTriangulo extends JComponent

{

     private double [] coordinatesX;
     private double [] coordinatesY;


    public graficadorTriangulo (double [] valoresX, double [] valoresY )
    {

        coordenadasX = valoresX;

        coordenadasY = valoresY;


    }



    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)

    {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Point2D.Double click1Pun = new Point2D.Double(coordenadasX[0], coordenadasY[0]);
        Point2D.Double click2Pun = new Point2D.Double(coordenadasX[1], coordenadasY[1]);
        Point2D.Double click3Pun=  new Point2D.Double(coordenadasX[2], coordenadasY[2]);

        Point2D.Double click4Pun = new Point2D.Double(coordenadasX[0]/2, coordenadasY[0]/2);

        Point2D.Double click1Mitad = new Point2D.Double(coordenadasX[0]/2, coordenadasY[0]/2);
        Point2D.Double click2Mitad = new Point2D.Double(coordenadasX[1]/2, coordenadasY[1]/2);
        Point2D.Double click3Mitad = new Point2D.Double(coordenadasX[2]/2, coordenadasY[2]/2);





        Line2D.Double ladoaLin = new Line2D.Double(click1Pun, click2Pun); 
        Line2D.Double ladobLin = new Line2D.Double(click1Pun, click3Pun);
        Line2D.Double ladocLin = new Line2D.Double(click2Pun, click3Pun);


        double magnitudA = Math.sqrt( ( (coordenadasX[1] - coordenadasX[0] ) * ( coordenadasX[1]- coordenadasX[0] ) ) + ( ( coordenadasY[1] - coordenadasY[0] ) * ( coordenadasY[1] - coordenadasY[0] ) ) );
        double magnitudB = Math.sqrt( ( (coordenadasX[2] - coordenadasX[1] ) * ( coordenadasX[2]- coordenadasX[1] ) ) + ( ( coordenadasY[2] - coordenadasY[1] ) * ( coordenadasY[2] - coordenadasY[1] ) ) );
        double magnitudC = Math.sqrt( ( (coordenadasX[0] - coordenadasX[2] ) * ( coordenadasX[0]- coordenadasX[2] ) ) + ( ( coordenadasY[0] - coordenadasY[2] ) * ( coordenadasY[0] - coordenadasY[2] ) ) );


        double perimetroTriangulo = magnitudA + magnitudB + magnitudC;


        double incentroNumeradorx = ((coordenadasX[0]*magnitudB)+(coordenadasX[1]*magnitudC)+(coordenadasX[2]*magnitudA));
        double incentroNumeradory = ((coordenadasY[0]*magnitudB)+(coordenadasY[1]*magnitudC)+(coordenadasY[2]*magnitudA));


        double incentroX  = incentroNumeradorx/perimetroTriangulo;
        double incentroY  = incentroNumeradory/perimetroTriangulo;





        Point2D.Double incentroPunto = new Point2D.Double(incentroX,incentroY);

        double magnitudD = Math.sqrt( ( (incentroX - coordenadasX[3] ) * ( incentroX- coordenadasX[3] ) ) + ( ( incentroY - coordenadasY[3] ) * ( incentroY - coordenadasY[3] ) ) );




        Line2D.Double centroaLin = new Line2D.Double(incentroPunto, click1Pun);
        Line2D.Double centrobLin = new Line2D.Double(incentroPunto, click2Pun);
        Line2D.Double centrocLin = new Line2D.Double(incentroPunto, click3Pun);


        double magPerpendicularX = coordenadasX[1] - coordenadasX[0];
        double magPerpendicularY = coordenadasY[1] - coordenadasY[0];



        double magnitudBase = sqrt(magPerpendicularX*magPerpendicularX + magPerpendicularY*magPerpendicularY);
        magPerpendicularX /= magnitudBase;
        magPerpendicularY /= magnitudBase ;

        double lambda = (magPerpendicularX * (incentroX - coordenadasX[0])) + (magPerpendicularY * (incentroY - coordenadasY[0]));
        double x4 = (magPerpendicularX * lambda) + coordenadasX[0];
        double y4 = (magPerpendicularY * lambda) + coordenadasY[0];



        Point2D.Double pointPerpendicular=  new Point2D.Double(x4,y4);

        Line2D.Double ladoH = new Line2D.Double(incentroPunto, pointPerpendicular);


       double magnitudRadioincentro= Math.sqrt( ( (x4 - incentroX ) * ( x4- incentroX ) ) + ( ( y4 - incentroY ) * ( y4 - incentroY ) ) );

        int magnitudDiametroincentro = (int)magnitudRadioincentro *2;    




        int x = (int)incentroX;
        int y = (int)incentroY;

        int x2 = (int)incentroX;
        int y2 = (int)incentroY;


          x = x-(magnitudDiametroincentro/2);
          y = y-(magnitudDiametroincentro/2);  



         double magnitudRadiocircuncentro = (magnitudA*magnitudB*magnitudC)/
                                           Math.sqrt((magnitudA+magnitudB+magnitudC)*
                                                     ((magnitudB+magnitudC)-magnitudA)*
                                                     ((magnitudC+magnitudA)-magnitudB)*
                                                     ((magnitudA+magnitudB)-magnitudC));
         int magnitudDiametrocircuncentro= (int)magnitudRadiocircuncentro *2;

           x2 = x2-(magnitudDiametrocircuncentro/2);
           y2 = y2-(magnitudDiametrocircuncentro/2);  
           g.setColor(Color.GREEN);     
           g.drawOval(x,y,magnitudDiametroincentro,magnitudDiametroincentro);
           g.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
           g.drawOval(x2,y2,magnitudDiametrocircuncentro,magnitudDiametrocircuncentro);


          double angle = (double) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2( coordenadasX[1] -  coordenadasX[0],  coordenadasY[1] -  coordenadasY[0]));

    if(angle < 0){
        angle += 360;



    }
        System.out.println("***********" + angle);
       g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(ladoaLin);
        g2.draw(ladobLin);
        g2.draw(ladocLin);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.draw(centroaLin); 
        g2.draw(centrobLin);
        g2.draw(centrocLin);


        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.draw(ladoH);

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given three points whose coordinates are:

(p,t) (q,u) (s,z)

...the equation of the circle defined by those three points is:

x^2 + y^2 + Ax + By + C = 0

where:
```

```
       A=((u-t)*z^2+(-u^2+t^2-q^2+p^2)*z+t*u^2+(-t^2+s^2-p^2)*u+(q^2-s^2)*t)/((q-p)*z+(p-s)*u+(s-q)*t)

       B=-((q-p)*z^2+(p-s)*u^2+(s-q)*t^2+(q-p)*s^2+(p^2-  q^2)*s+p*q^2-p^2*q)/((q-p)*z+(p-s)*u+(s-q)*t)

       C=-((p*u-q*t)*z^2+(-p*u^2+q*t^2-p*q^2+p^2*q)*z+s*t*u^2+(-s*t^2+p*s^2-p^2*s)*u+(q^2*s-q*s^2)*t)/((q-p)*z+(p-s)*u+(s-q)*t)
```

````
The above is the general solution. You can put the formulas for A, B, and C into your program and find the equation for any circle, given 3 points.

For your particular problem with points (0,1) (1,0) (0,-1) you will get:

A=0

B=0

C=-1

... so the equation will be

x^2 + y^2 -1 = 0 (the unit circle

Comment: I´m so sorry your answer was absolutly right but I forgot to mark it as the right answer. I know It´s really late but thanks a lot mate